# Passing values from Greasemonkey sandbox into anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, addeventlistener, userscripts

This is my first question, probably very silly indeed :)

I have a selection of values in an array, returned from GM_listValues().
As I loop over the collection, I want to dynamically create buttons that call a function to delete the stored value, and reload the page.

```
deleteB.addEventListener("click", function() {deleteTrip(names[i]);pageSelect();}, false);
```

Above is the line I am using to attach the event to the button (`deleteB`). However, when I press the button, javascript tries to access the array of listValues (`names`) with the count variable (`i`). Naturally, this will not exist, as the loop is now done, and `names` is not global anyway.

What I want to know is if there is a way to copy the string value of `names[i]` while I am creating the function in the button, so as to not need a reference to `names[i]` in the code.

I know this is probably a really simple answer, but its got me stumped, this is some of my first work with javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a closure to remember the value;

```
function createDeleteFunc(name) {
  return function(){deleteTrip(name);pageSelect();}
}

for() {
...
deleteB.addEventListener("click", createDeleteFunc(names[i]), false);
...
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was not on the net over the weekend. Thanks for the solution, it worked perfectly. Something I'll have to remember in the future!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all functions you create reference the same `i` variable. When they are called, they try to delete `names[i]`, but `i` is now equal to `names.length` so it doesn't work.

The solution is to make a separate reference to `names[i]` for each function. This is usually done with a closure (à-la Paul's answer)